# Proper way of Apple in app purchase with free trial in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-subscription, promotions

**I am coding in Flutter, and I want to implement an auto-renewable subscription with a 3day free trial period.**

Unfortunately, I did not find any exact documentation or advice, how can I test it.

**What I tried:**

1) I created an auto-renewable product in the apple developer console.
2) inside this product I have chosen the “add promotional offer”, where I selected the “free trial”

Everything was easy and clear, but when I start my application for testing this, it only displays the normal price, and I find nowhere the free trial part. So I can not test it.

When I call the subscribe method, it will show me the normal price to charge. When I subscribe to my sandbox user, I do not see anything about the free trial in the validation JSON.

**Is this normal?** Could it be possible, that the free trial feature is available only in production?
Or what did I forget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the settings of the in-app purchase item from app/play store, there is an option to add an introductory/trial offer where you can mention the trial period. In the code, you can deliver the item accordingly.